# proximal policy gradient tensorflow pendulum issue

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, agent, openai-gym

```
import gym  
import numpy as np  
import tensorflow as tf


class Memory(object):  
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.ep_obs, self.ep_act, self.ep_rwd, self.ep_neglogp = [], [], [], []

    def store_transition(self, obs0, act, rwd, neglogp):
        self.ep_obs.append(obs0)
        self.ep_act.append(act)
        self.ep_rwd.append(rwd)
        self.ep_neglogp.append(neglogp)

    def covert_to_array(self):
        array_obs = np.vstack(self.ep_obs)
        array_act = np.vstack(self.ep_act)
        array_rwd = np.array(self.ep_rwd)
        array_neglogp = np.array(self.ep_neglogp).squeeze(axis=1)
        return array_obs, array_act, array_rwd, array_neglogp

    def reset(self):
        self.ep_obs, self.ep_act, self.ep_rwd, self.ep_neglogp = [], [], [], []


class ActorNetwork(object):
    
    def __init__(self, act_dim, name):
        self.act_dim = act_dim
        self.name = name

    def step(self, obs, reuse):
        with tf.variable_scope(self.name, reuse=reuse):
            h1 = tf.layers.dense(obs, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            mu = 2 * tf.layers.dense(h1, self.act_dim, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
            sigma = tf.layers.dense(h1, self.act_dim, activation=tf.nn.softplus)
            pd = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        return pd

    def choose_action(self, obs, reuse=False):
        pd = self.step(obs, reuse)
        action = tf.squeeze(pd.sample(1), axis=0)
        action = tf.clip_by_value(action, -2, 2)
        return action

    def get_neglogp(self, obs, act, reuse=False):
        pd = self.step(obs, reuse)
        logp = pd.log_prob(act)
        return logp


class ValueNetwork(object):
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def step(self, obs, reuse):
        with tf.variable_scope(self.name, reuse=reuse):
            h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=obs, units=100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            value = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h1, units=1)
            return value

    def get_value(self, obs, reuse=False):
        value = self.step(obs, reuse)
        return value


class PPO(object):
    
    def __init__(self, act_dim, obs_dim, lr_actor, lr_value, gamma, clip_range):
        self.act_dim = act_dim
        self.obs_dim = obs_dim
        self.lr_actor = lr_actor
        self.lr_value = lr_value
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.clip_range = clip_range

        self.OBS = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.obs_dim], name="observation")
        self.ACT = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.act_dim], name="action")
        self.Q_VAL = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="q_value")
        self.ADV = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="advantage")
        self.NEGLOGP = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="old_neglogp")

        actor = ActorNetwork(self.act_dim, 'actor')
        value = ValueNetwork('critic')
        self.memory = Memory()

        self.action = actor.choose_action(self.OBS)
        self.neglogp = actor.get_neglogp(self.OBS, self.ACT, reuse=True)
        ratio = tf.math.exp(self.neglogp - self.NEGLOGP)
        clip_ratio = tf.clip_by_value(ratio, 1. - self.clip_range, 1. + self.clip_range)
        actor_loss = -tf.reduce_mean((tf.minimum(ratio* self.ADV, clip_ratio* self.ADV)) )
        self.actor_train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr_actor).minimize(actor_loss)

        self.value = value.get_value(self.OBS)
        self.advantage = self.Q_VAL - self.value
        value_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.advantage))
        self.value_train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr_value).minimize(value_loss)

        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    def step(self, obs):
        if obs.ndim < 2: obs = obs[np.newaxis, :]
        action = self.sess.run(self.action, feed_dict={self.OBS: obs})
        action = np.squeeze(action, 1).clip(-2, 2)

        neglogp = self.sess.run(self.neglogp, feed_dict={self.OBS: obs, self.ACT: action[np.newaxis, :]})

        value = self.sess.run(self.value, feed_dict={self.OBS: obs})
        value = np.squeeze(value, 1).squeeze(0)
        return action, neglogp, value

    def learn(self, last_value, done):
        obs, act, rwd, neglogp = self.memory.covert_to_array()
        rwd = (rwd - rwd.mean()) / (rwd.std() + 1e-5)
        q_value = self.compute_q_value(last_value, obs, rwd)

        adv = self.sess.run(self.advantage, {self.OBS: obs, self.Q_VAL: q_value})

        [self.sess.run(self.value_train_op,
                       {self.OBS: obs, self.Q_VAL: q_value}) for _ in range(10)]
        [self.sess.run(self.actor_train_op,
                          {self.OBS: obs, self.ACT: act, self.ADV: adv, self.NEGLOGP: neglogp}) for _ in range(10)]

        self.memory.reset()

    def compute_q_value(self, last_value, obs, rwd):
        q_value = np.zeros_like(rwd)
        value = self.sess.run(self.value, feed_dict={self.OBS: obs})
        for t in reversed(range(0, len(rwd)-1)):
            q_value[t] = value[t+1] * self.gamma + rwd[t]
        return q_value[:, np.newaxis]


env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
env.seed(1)
env = env.unwrapped

agent = PPO(act_dim=env.action_space.shape[0], obs_dim=env.observation_space.shape[0],
            lr_actor=0.0004, lr_value=0.0003, gamma=0.9, clip_range=0.2)

nepisode = 1000
nstep = 200

for i_episode in range(nepisode):
    obs0 = env.reset()
    ep_rwd = 0

    for t in range(nstep):
        act, neglogp, _ = agent.step(obs0)
        obs1, rwd, done, _ = env.step(act)

        agent.memory.store_transition(obs0, act, rwd, neglogp)

        obs0 = obs1
        ep_rwd += rwd

        if (t + 1) % 32 == 0 or t == nstep - 1:
            _, _, last_value = agent.step(obs1)
            agent.learn(last_value, done)

    print('Ep: %i' % i_episode, "|Ep_r: %i" % ep_rwd)
```

I've implemented proximal policy optimization on tensorflow, enviroment pendulum v0

1. if there is something wrong above tell me, why my code its not working, it's days that im trying to fix this, but my pendulum doesnt converge, I dont see what can be wrong ?
   can someone help?
   I've implemented proximal policy optimization on tensorflow, enviroment pendulum v0
2. Im implementing a reinforcement learning algorithm, Im trying so hard to make this code to work no success;